# How can I create a Firefox extension that changes the new tab page behavior?

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am completely new to Firefox extension development so please let me know if there is a more appropriate place to post this question.

I want to create an extension for Firefox similar to Momentum or Tabliss that redefines the new tab page. I have some html/css/js files that I can run on a local server that work as desired. But I'd like to create an extension so I can view this stuff when I make a new tab. I have tried extensions to point to a local file on new tab but these are no longer allowed by Firefox.

I don't want to host it as a website and have the new tab open to a url. I specifically want to create an extension like Momentum or Tabliss that completely changes the new tab page.

Are there any resources I should look at to figure out how to do this? What specifically allows an extension to change the new tab page behavior?

Thank you for any help

Comment: I think you may be looking for chrome_url_overrides key in manifest.json https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides