# Firefox JS Extension | How do I access the new tab and the homepage of Firefox to inject my new page?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

I've been following many Firefox addon / extension examples and searched the "tab" documentation; however, I still haven't found how to use my newly created index.html page as a new tab or homepage for Firefox.

I want to create something like [Momentum](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/momentumdash/?src=search). A personal dashboard for Firefox.

This is what I have until now. However, because I'm creating a new tab on `tabs.onCreated`, I'm creating an infinite loop in new tabs.

**Manifest.json**

```
{

  "description": "Adds browser action icon to toolbar to open packaged web page. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples#open-my-page-button",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Bookify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/open-my-page-button",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.jpg",
    "videos/*.mp4"
  ]

}
```

**Background.js**

```
function openMyPage() {
    browser.tabs.create({
        "url": "/dash.html"
    });
}

browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(openMyPage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ramkumar K R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2623762/ramkumar-k-r)'s answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728570/how-can-i-create-a-firefox-extension-that-changes-the-new-tab-page-behavior) question, I implemented the following inside my manifest.json:

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
   "newtab": "index.html"
 }
```

So if anyone wants to know how to change the newtab page in Firefox, use [chrome_url_overrides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides). Because the referred question has not been officially "answered", I'm gonna leave this question and answer it myself so other developers can find their answer here.